# JavaScript error only in IE8 compatability mode and IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, superfish, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am getting an annoying error only in IE7 and IE8's compatibility mode. FireFox and other browsers work fine.

The site is here:

http://174.136.92.214/test/test.html

Looking at the error and the code seems to show that something is wrong inside the SuperFish/jQuery code which seems surprising.

Any help would be appreciated.

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0;
>   .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 2 Mar 2011 21:13:57
>   UTC
>
> Message: Expected identifier, string
>   or number Line: 23 Char: 13 Code: 0
>   URI:
>   http://174.136.92.214/test/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove extra comma after:

```
 speed:         'fast',
```

Comment: That's what I would have guessed without even looking at the problem.

Comment: I must be blind then. Thank you for seeing the obvious.